# Generate Java POJO model from JsonSchema (preferably using JAXB)

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, jsonschema

We have an abstract data model defined via JSON Schema.  Obviously, we can use XSD instead if we had to, with some tweaks here and there.  However, our POJOs are used interchangeably over both XML and JSON data stores, and for business reasons we want the schema to be JSON Schema.

I would like to use this JSON Schema to generate a Java class model via JAXB.  In other words, rather than pass XSD as the input to JAXB, we want to use JSON Schema as the source file instead.  I see two ways to do this.

1. Write a JSON Schema-to-XSD converter.  (There is a library out there called [json2xsd](https://github.com/ethlo/jsons2xsd) that might preclude us from having to write our own compiler.)  Feed the resulting XSD file into JAXB.
2. Write a parser that converts JSON Schema into the intermediate data structure [com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model](https://github.com/javaee/jaxb-v2/blob/master/jaxb-ri/xjc/src/main/java/com/sun/tools/xjc/model/Model.java), which JAXB uses as the input to its code generator.

Offhand, I would prefer the second option to avoid a needless intermediate schema, but I cannot find any documentation online on how to create an effective Model.  It would appear I'd have to do a lot of code diving to figure out exactly what needs to go into this model.  Has anyone done this before?  Is there documentation out there that I am overlooking?  Any thoughts on which is actually the better approach?

(PS - Yes, I've looked at [jsonschema2pojo](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo), which would remove JAXB entirely from the picture.  However, I'm very unsatisfied with its coverage of the JSON Schema specs (it's four drafts behind and doesn't even support that one fully), and I'd rather rely on a more solid code generator foundation like JAXB.)